# Language Compatibility on Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: language-support

Will I be able to see and write other language on Ubuntu desktop? Where do I download the language and how do I install it?

Comment: Check out the relevant section in [the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/prefs-language.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Will I be able to see and write other language on Ubuntu desktop?

Yes, I tend to have both English and Dutch active. English for my own user account and Dutch for the account I administer. I have English/US and English/US with dead keys on this account.

> Where do I download the language and how do I install it?

From system settings (cog wheel in the panel) or from "dash", search for "languages".

[image]

[image]

Settings for numbers and date are in the 2nd tab:

[image]

You can choose the INPUT language in the panel:

[image]

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the last figure is about the input language, while the rest of the answer explains how to set the language for displaying menus and messages. That's two different things.